# mysql check if a value is in a range or not

Tags: mysql, range, mariadb, limit

I have a mysql (mariadb) table of pictures with the id and score of them, like this:

```
TABLE Pics
-----------
id   points
-----------
1    500
2    10
3    150
4    70
...
```

The table has more columns and can have a lot of registers.

I want to know how to know if a picture could be tagged as "popular". For the system, "popular" would be the **1% of pictures with more points**. So, if I have 1.000 pictures in the table, just the 10 pictures with more points would be tagged as "popular".

So, how could be the query to know if the picture with a given id is popular or not?

Many thanks!

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website.  Post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can try to fix it.  If you can't even do this simple query, then you should probably not touch the database.

Comment: Do you have access to latest version of MySQL (version >= 8.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a `LIMIT` clause after sorting them by score to only select the 10 most popular photos or if you need to select all the photos, you can use a variable like the following query :

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT IF((@rank := @rank + 1) <= 10, "popular", "unpopular"), p.*
    FROM picture_table AS p
    ORDER BY p.score DESC;
```

if you need the limit to be dynamic, you can do a first query to evaluate the total number of elements and use it in that query like so :

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @limit = 10/100; -- 10%

SELECT (@limit := ROUND(COUNT(ID) * @limit)) FROM picture_table;

SELECT IF((@rank := @rank + 1) <= @limit, "popular", "unpopular"), p.*
    FROM picture_table AS p
    ORDER BY p.score DESC;
```

Now with that query, you can use a subquery to determine if a particular picture is popular :

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @limit = 10/100;

SELECT (@limit := ROUND(COUNT(ID) * @limit)) FROM picture_table;

SELECT Q1.popularity, p.* 
    FROM picture_table AS p
    INNER JOIN (SELECT IF((@rank := @rank + 1) <= @limit, "popular", "unpopular") AS 'popularity', p.ID
        FROM picture_table AS p
        ORDER BY p.score DESC) AS Q1 ON Q1.ID = p.ID
    WHERE p.ID = 16;
```

Keep in mind it is better to limit the amount of data generated by the sub query to the bare minimum so that the query keeps a good performance when the database gets bigger.

[Here's](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nKb3zyLLoDZCDiV2jd2dBz/0) a DB-Fiddle with all those scripts with working sample data

Comment: I don't want an absolute value like 10. I would like a relative value as 1%

Comment: @Ommadawn `SET @max = (SELECT COUNT(*) * 0.2 FROM picture_table)`

Comment: Then `IF ((@rank := @rank + 1) <= @max, "popular", "unpopular")`

Comment: you can't use `SET` in an expression, it should be `@rank := @rank + 1`

Comment: @barmar my bad, I forgot

Comment: but... if I have the Pic with id=77, how would I know if it is a popular Pic or not?

Comment: @ommadawn you can do a subquery for that. Keep in mind though that you must limit the data you use in the subquery to a minimum to that the query doesn't take a year to execute.

Comment: One question. Using that query in Hibernate, which method should I use? uniqueResult()? getResultList()? I don't know how to handle that kind of querys.

Comment: @ommadawn I am not completely sure, but I would say `uniqueResult()`. that method ensures that the query returns a single result and you already deal with a single object instead of a list containing that same object.

Comment: Yes. The point is... Will I need to run 3 separated queries or is there an option to do it using only one that runs the 3 sentences at the same time?

Comment: it kind of depends on the data you want to get from the query, but basically, each query will be executed independently. so you need to perform a query for the set of data you want and then work with it.

Comment: Thanks. In your answer to my post, the third solution you gave me there are 4 sentences (separated by semicolons). I want to retrieve the last result, but I don't know if it's a good practice to run 4 independent querys. Maybe there's a solution to unify these 4 sentences in just one calling with hibernate?